# I deployed react build but I got a white blank page only

Tags: reactjs, azure, nginx

I use AzureAppService and I deployed to nginx on Linux.
I googled "react white blank page" and I append `"homepage": "."`.
I got a white page still after I rebuilt and deployed it.
What's happened? Tell me how to visible react page.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Okay. Finally, I got react page.
I accessed the old URL...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others facing the same issue.